how to add tooltip in google chat to button
I have a list of values, I have to add this list values in google chat using card v2 button template and when user hover on the button in the google chat, the full description for that button is also visible to user.

If you use icon only for the button, you can altText attribute, here is the example:

              {
                "icon": {
                  "knownIcon": "INVITE",
                  "altText": "check calendar"
                },
                "onClick": {
                  "openLink": {
                    "url": "https://developers.google.com/chat/ui/widgets/button-list"
                  }
                }
              }

But if you have a text on the button, using altText might not work.
reference:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/cards#Message.Button_1
